# Using strings inside structures

Tags: c, arrays, string

```
struct employee
{
    char name[20];
}emp;

void main()
{
    emp.name[20]="John";
    printf("%s\n",emp.name);
}
```

why does this code give no output?
Why is it impossible to initialize the string array directly?

Comment: Access beyond array.

Comment: Trying to write a pointer to char (aka "pseudo string") into a char.

Comment: Probably does not print because emp.name[0] is `'\0'`.

Comment: @Yunnosch  Felix explained it pretty well in answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Assign string to element in structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179833/assign-string-to-element-in-structure-in-c)

Comment: @FilipKočica I fail to see an explaination for the completely missing output ("no output"), only for the missing correct output. And the answer is younger than my comments. What is your point?

Comment: @OmG duplicate is *very* close, but misses on the error of trying to assign to an array *including an index* :o

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Your compiler should **warn** you. If you use `gcc`, try compiling this with

```
gcc -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

and see.

The issue is just wrong syntax. you're assigning your string literal to `emp.name[20]` which is the **21st element**  of `emp.name`. This element doesn't even exist and it has the type `char`.

What you want would be something like:

```
emp.name = "John"; // <- INVALID!!
```

But this doesn't work, because C unfortunately doesn't allow to *assign* to an array. You can use the function `strcpy` (string copy) to achieve what you want, though (include `string.h`):

```
strcpy(emp.name, "John");
```

Comment: Prefer strncpy for safety reasons.

Comment: @Yunnosch never ever use `strncpy()`, it has very bad semantics (e.g. it doesn't guarantee `NUL` termination of the result). If you can't be sure the result fits, do your own calculations with `strlen()`.

Comment: "Never ever" as in "not even if the string to copy is of unknown origin and unknown length"? I know it is not the case here, but "never ever" is inappropriate.

Comment: @Yunnosch it's very appropriate as using `strncpy()` in this case will leave you with something that **isn't a string**.

Comment: When using strncpy, handling the termination is part of the job. I thought that implicit.

Comment: Sorry for  the silliness but how is it possible to use char arr[20]="John" but not this one?

Comment: @HiruniNimanthi YW. feel free to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it (after some time to allow for potentially better answers) if it solved your problem. If something is still unclear, wait for a better answer or ask for further clarification :)

Comment: Sorry for the silliness but how is it possible to use char arr[20]="John" but not this one?

Comment: @HiruniNimanthi `char arr[20]="John";` is not an *assignment* but *initialization*. Initialization of an array is possible (giving it an initial content at declaration), but assignment to an array isn't allowed in C.

Comment: @HiruniNimanthi also note that in the declaration `char arr[20]`, the `20` determines the **size** of the array, but when you later write `arr[20]`, you refer to its **21st element** which is *out of bounds*. `arr[0]` to `arr[19]` would be valid and refer to a *single character* of your array.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Always use `strncpy()` followed by a `dest[_countof(dest)-1] = '\0';`. This (a) uses a standard library function to avoid buffer overflow and (b) ensures the terminating '`\0'`

Comment: @harper now, what is `_countof`? If you can do this, you don't need `strncpy()`. This function is ill-defined and the best way to go about it is to avoid it.

Comment: @FelixPalmen `_countof` is a macro in the header files counting the elements of an array like `#define _countof(a) (sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]))` . If you're sure that you have ANSI char (not wide char) and your compiler does not include `_countof` then you cane replace it by `sizeof`. You NEED `strncpy` since `strcpy` can give you a buffer overrun.

Comment: @harper `_countof` doesn't exist in C. Never use extensions you don't **need** (and you don't need this, `sizeof dest / sizeof *dest` gives you the number of elements and is a compile-time constant). There's **no** situation where `strncpy()` gives you anything. In the worst case, you could do a simple `memcpy()`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen I wrote how you can replace `_countof`, didn't I? Use a replacement or define a macro, it's your choice. You missed the buffer overrun problem. How do you avoid it, if the source string (a char* in C) has not a predefined length or even worse has no terminating `'\0'`?

Comment: @harper no I didn't. Read up on `memcpy()`, it has a size parameter. That's not a great option, but if you're prepared to cut off a part of your string, it's actually better than `strncpy()` because it doesn't bother to parse anything as a string in the first place, and it doesn't have a misleading name that implies the result would be a **string**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152942/discussion-between-harper-and-felix-palmen).

Answer (score 2):

The statement `emp.name[20]="John";` has a few problems. The intention appears to be to assign the string `"John"` to the character array `emp.name`. But, you can't assign to character arrays (you can initialize them). `"John"` is a string literal, which decays to a pointer to the first element of an array of `char` in the assignment expression, so this statement is attempting to assign a pointer to `char` to `emp.name[20]`, which isn't a character array anyway, but would be a `char`, except that `emp.name[20]` is an attempted out-of-bounds array access. Remember that arrays are zero-indexed in C, so the first element of the array is `emp.name[0]`, and the last index is `emp.name[19]`. Finally, even if this assignment was to a valid element of the array, you certainly don't mean to assign a pointer to a `char`.

One solution would be to make `emp` local to `main()`, and use an initializer. Note that the function signature for `main()` should be one of `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char **argv)`; any other function signature here is implementation-dependent. Also, I assume that the original code did not forget to `#include <stdio.h>`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee
{
    char name[20];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct employee emp = { .name = "John" };

    printf("%s\n",emp.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `strcpy()` without changing `emp`. One disadvantage to this approach is that you must be careful not to attempt to copy a string larger than `emp.name[]`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct employee
{
    char name[20];
} emp;

int main(void)
{
    strcpy(emp.name, "John");

    printf("%s\n",emp.name);

    return 0;
}
```

The designated initializer could have also been used at file scope with the original `struct` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct employee
{
    char name[20];
} emp = { .name = "John" };

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n",emp.name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Emp.name[20] is taking the index of the 20th position of the array name. So it will throw an error.
U can write ur code in this way using
     strcpy()

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>
 struct employee
 {
      char name[20];
 }emp;

void main()
{
    // emp.name="John";
     strcpy(emp.name,"john");
      printf("%s\n",emp.name);
 }
```