# expression must be a modifiable lvalue error in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct, error-handling, char

I am trying to assign empty to some strings using struct in c by this code:

```
void initializer(table* s)
{
    for(int i = 0 ;i<N;i++)
    {
        s[i].name= "Empty";

    }
}
```

and this in main function

```
table s[N];
initializer(s);
```

This is my struct :

```
struct table {
    char name[10];
    int marks;
} ;

typedef struct table table;
```

I still have to declare marks as -1 but I guess that shouldn't solve this error;

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: You need to show the struct declaration or otherwise the question can't be answered.

Comment: Without at least the definition of `table` it will be impossible to aid you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Assign string to element in structure in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12179833/assign-string-to-element-in-structure-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign a string to a char array. use `strlcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

An object can be modified with `=` operator only if it is an modifiable L-value. From [6.3.2.1p1](https://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p1):

> ... A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that **does not have array type**, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const- qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const- qualified type.

The type of `name` member is `char[10]` so it cannot be assigned using `=` operator. Use a dedicated function `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(s[i].name, "Empty");
```